# Python Dictionary Key and Values Question

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

- I have a list of tuples that I wish to use as values for my new
  dictionary.
- I have a list of strings that I wish to use as keys for
  my new dictionary.
- However I want to use the capital city as a key
  for the nested dictionary.

```
    users = [
        (0, "Bob", "Paris", "password"),
        (1, "Jack", "Berlin", "python"),
        (2, "Jenna", "London" ,"overflow"),
        (3, "Eva", "Stockholm" ,"1234")
    ]
    
    
    office_employees = ["id","Name","key"]
```

The output I expect is the following:

```
    {'Paris':{"id":0,"Name":"Bob",key:"password"},'Berlin':{"id":1,"Name":"Jack",key:"python"},"London":{"id":2,"Name":"Jenna",key:"overflow"},"Stockholm":{"id":3,"Name":"Eva",key:"1234"}}
```

Therefore I used dictionary comprehension. I tried various filtering options but it does not seem to work in any way.

```
    {item[2]: dict(zip(office_employees, item)) for index, item in enumerate(users)}
```

The output I receive:

```
    {'Berlin': {'Name': 'Jack', 'id': 1, 'key': 'Berlin'},
     'London': {'Name': 'Jenna', 'id': 2, 'key': 'London'},
     'Paris': {'Name': 'Bob', 'id': 0, 'key': 'Paris'},
     'Stockholm': {'Name': 'Eva', 'id': 3, 'key': 'Stockholm'}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore I used dictionary comprehension.

Don't use dictionary comprehension if it's not convenient.

```
d = {}
for u in users:
    id_, name, capital, key = u
    d[capital] = {
        'id': id_,
        'Name': name,
        'key': key
    }
```

It's infinitely more simple this way.

Comment: What's wrong with: `{c: {'id': i, 'Name': n, 'key': k} for i, n, c, k in users}`?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what You want? just need to use indexes:

```py
users = [
        (0, "Bob", "Paris", "password"),
        (1, "Jack", "Berlin", "python"),
        (2, "Jenna", "London" ,"overflow"),
        (3, "Eva", "Stockholm" ,"1234")
    ]


office_employees = ["id","Name","key"]

d = {item[2]: dict(zip(office_employees, (item[0], item[1], item[3]))) for item in users}
print(d)
```

So basically for the zipping You can just use:

```py
dict(zip(office_employees, (item[0], item[1], item[3])))
```

Comment: Hey @Matiiss thank you for the answer. Yes that is exactly what I am looking for. I will accept the post as an answer.

Comment: thank You but I will have to admit that the other answer that does not use dictionary comprehension is way more readable and the only downside would be if You were to use these to create **enormously huge** amounts of data then my solution could be slightly faster maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little ugly way to achieve what you want.

code:

```
users = [
        (0, "Bob", "Paris", "password"),
        (1, "Jack", "Berlin", "python"),
        (2, "Jenna", "London" ,"overflow"),
        (3, "Eva", "Stockholm" ,"1234")
    ]
office_employees = ["id","Name","key"]
ans = {}
for user in users:
    ans[user[2]]={office_employees[0]:user[0],office_employees[1]:user[1],office_employees[2]:user[3]}
print(ans)
```

result:

```
{'Paris': {'id': 0, 'Name': 'Bob', 'key': 'password'}, 'Berlin': {'id': 1, 'Name': 'Jack', 'key': 'python'}, 'London': {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Jenna', 'key': 'overflow'}, 'Stockholm': {'id': 3, 'Name': 'Eva', 'key': '1234'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to get the capital city into another array before creating the nested dictionary.

cap_cities = [ user[2] for user in users ]

Comment: this is not a qualitative answer, that is why I will downvote it, You should improve it by adding more meaningful stuff

Comment: @Matiiss It is an alternative for anyone who likes to go slow.

Comment: but you are not giving the full solution You just state that something has to be created, You should provide how this can be applied, how the expected output can be produced out of this